# Does a sort key in dynamo sort even with different partition keys?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Getting acclimated to DynamoDB : )

If I have a table with a unique partition key, like a unique id, and I use a time stamp as a sort key, how will Dynamo sort my data?

Will I have the most recent things in one partition, and the older things in other partitions?

I ask because I want to know how to assign throughput, and I'm certain my recently created and edited items will be most likely to be accessed, and the old stuff can pretty much be archived.

Comment: No - the sort key only applies within each partition. There is no implied ordering at the partition level, nor across partitions.

Comment: Hmmm.... I've seen an example for how to do this... Here it is: https://youtu.be/BEbiE2UV5Sc?t=20m48s It seems you have to create multiple tables on the fly. Hmm... wonder if there's another way.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamodb keeps all the items of a particular partition key in one partition. For eg, if there are 10 items available for a specific partition key with different timestamps, all the 10 items will be present on single partition. So that when the data is retrieved for a partition key, all the items can be retrieved from single partition. This makes the retrieval process faster.

Reg the sorting, Dynamodb sorts the data for the particular partition key. You can use the ScanIndexForward parameter to sort the data by ascending or descending order.